# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pixel'

Tags: python

the image variable comes from a text file (containing numbers, which i assume that they are a string in python). So what was i'm trying to do is to typecast the "pixel" variable (which is string elements from the text file) to an integer so that I could divide them. but the error in the title above shows. Is there a way to typecast it with it staying in the index? Thanks!

```
def getHist (image, bins):
    hist = [0 for e in range(0,bins)] 
    interval = 256//bins
    for row in image: 
        for pixel in row:
            hist[int(pixel)//interval] += 1 
    return hist


def printHist (hist):
    for i in range(0, len(hist)):
        print(i+1,"-", hist[i], "\t- ", end="")
        for j in range(0, hist[i]): 
            print("|", end="")
        print()

def readImage (filename):
    image = []
    fileHandle = open(filename, "r") 
    for line in fileHandle: 
        image_row = line[0:-1].split(",") 
        image_row[-1] = image_row[-1][0:len(line)].split("\n") 
        image.append(image_row) 
    fileHandle.close() 
    return image

image = readImage("image.txt") 
hist = getHist("image.txt",8) 
printHist(hist)
```

Here is an example for the image parameter (from a text file):

```
212,16,142,183,92,211,0,221,54,226
227,56,137,252,140,241,1,3,153,51
157,144,121,99,17,185,125,27,76,129
49,55,81,220,194,8,62,179,96,142
74,178,80,24,2,34,247,177,244,82
93,117,154,152,35,224,38,70,193,52
181,61,45,141,163,222,160,168,203,104
234,114,244,53,252,48,66,7,218,95
49,189,18,31,184,207,53,141,148,188
238,6,104,189,244,132,28,92,147,123
```

where each row, each element is the pixel

the file loaded by a different function on my program, but yeah. i'm trying to convert each pixel to a int so that i could divide it with another int.

Comment: `int("pixel")` -> `int(pixel)`

Comment: i tried that too but sadly, it still shows the error

Comment: Without knowing what type `pixel` is, then it's impossible to say what you're trying to do or how this should work. After changing that code, though, there's no way you could still be getting the error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pixel'`. The error message is probably different now so you should include that. As well as the type of `image`, `row` and `pixel`.

Comment: yeah. i'm also confused if i missed out on something. cause if we typecast it with int() then it would change to integer, but it won't. i'll edit my post and try to include an example.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: i already edited the post. sorry!

Comment: You're passing a string to getHistogram via `getHistogram("image.txt",8)` so when you do `for row in image:`, you're actually iterating over the characters in the string!

Comment: Plus, what's with the slicing with `[0:-1]` and later `image_row[-1][0:-1].split("\n")`. I suggest you print the `image` retuned from `readImage` just to make sure that you really want the last element of each row to be a list with length 1.

Comment: yeah. i'm passing a string(which are really numbers) unto the function. then i should divide those numbers so i need them o be an integer. and that is where the problem comes in

Comment: i'll try looking up the slicing part. thanks!

Comment: thank you @JustinEzequiel for mentioning about the slicing part. i've already fixed it, but i'm still unable to fix my problem on turning the strings to integers

Comment: i'm passing a string(which are really numbers) - no you are not. You are passing the filename. Not the contents.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
histogram = getHistogram("image.txt",8)
```

with

```
histogram = getHistogram(image, 8)
```

Otherwise you're iterating over the filename instead of the data from the file!

Comment: i think that fixed my problem! although i got a new problem, though probably from another part of the program. anyways. thank you!